Add node.js module into PHP Apache Application for real-time communication through websockets?
I have a dedicated, managed VM on top of which I host my web app, running on PHP (FCGI) and Apache. I built a REST API in PHP, everything of the web app is an endpoint, basically. That includes the chat messaging functionality included in the app, which is thus implemented using polling to simulate real-time messaging.
I would now like to really have an actual real-time messaging solution, but ideally with as much of the codebase written in PHP being used, and a minimum amount of added work as possible.
So I first looked at solutions for websockets in PHP, but I keep reading about articles saying that PHP is not the best for websockets.
So I thought about the following architecture:

Install an additional node.js directory on my VM
In that directory, setup a websocket server responsible for the handling of ws connections
When a client successfully logs in, establish a new connection to the websocket server. The whole application traffic is though still going throught the REST API as until now. The ws connection is exclusively used to forward received messages to the corresponding client in real-time.
Create an endpoint on the node.js server, e.g. POST /forward-messages, taking an array of e.g. {message: string, id: int} objects as request arguments. When a request is received on that endpoint, the message is sent to the respective user ids provided in the request that are currently connected with the ws server.
When a new message is sent through the REST API (e.g. POST /messages endpoint), everything stays as it is, plus: the endpoint POST /forward-messages is triggered accordingly, internally.

I'm thinking of this solution because the messaging system setup is very tightly coupled to other components of the app, so rewriting the entire logic of it within node.js would take a significant amount of time and is at least currently not an option.
Is there any risk in this setup?

If PHP is not feasible for WebSockets for you, then you can implement a middleware in the technology of your choice, NodeJS seems to be it. The middleware would nor include any of the data processing, it would just handle the duplex WebSocket communication with the browser/app of the user and parse the events during the interaction with the browser/app into calls to your PHP app.
So you will not have to migrate large codes from your app into NodeJS (you may decide to do so anytime, but you will not be forced to do so), but you will delegate the middleware abilities to NodeJS which will be a "postman" between the user browser/app and your PHP server-side. That way you will only need to implement a lightweight middleware that will keep the duplex channels up and running, receive some commands from the client-side, convert them into action calls that your PHP application can understand, send the requests (or execute command-line PHP, whatever method you prefer), get the answer that PHP provides and transmit it through the WebSocket duplex channel to the client-side.

Yeah that's precisely my plan. So am I understanding it correctly that you do not see any risks with this setup? There are just two things I'm not sure about, A) is authentication: This setup requires that exclusively authenticated users should be allowed to initiate a websocket connection. And I guess session validity must be checked when both sending a new message (done in PHP Controller) and reception? B) would you recommend any specific way / protocol used to forward messages from PHP to node.js (HTTP, CLI, etc.) ?

@DevelJoe having a middleware will not create new risks if you keep it thin. You will only need to implement the WebSocket support and the bridge between the two sides. If you do not move over your PHP stuff, even if you fail, you will not have invested too much time and effort into it. Authentication would happen via PHP and your client-side would receive an access token or something of the like which could be passed to the middleware. It would then pass the access token to PHP to verify it and if valid, then issue the connection, error out otherwise.

Also, if you know about a solution in PHP, even better, feel free to let me know. what I need would be exactly something like this: http://socketo.me/docs/push., so if there's a MQ feature added, even better. With ratchet our current problem is that its latest release dates back to 2021 and that it's currently looking for funding for a major update, according to https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/commit/d77c7bcd07978f3b8bb879ce74056c2f75dd60a2.

@DevelJoe so you issue your new session via PHP and have some token in the client-side cookie that can use it to issue a WebSocket connection. Of course you will need your PHP to keep track of your tokens. As about B, you could use a message queue such as RabbitMQ, or you could have some messages in Redis or something which your NodeJS could periodically check for. But, ideally you would minimalize the communication initiated from PHP to WebSocket, ideally to 0 so you would only have the WebSocket system issuing communication with PHP. Not a necessity, but it would be good.

@DevelJoe the problem with PHP is that it was not designed to have multiple threads, so implementing this in PHP would be hacky and unpleasant. I experimented with this back in 2018, I believe and did not really like my solution. NodeJS, with its event loop is also not the best in my opinion, but it's good-enough. PHP by design is not well-suited for Websockets (see https://dev.to/robertobutti/websocket-with-php-4k2c). It's solvable, but you will find yourself in a dark place if you choose this route.

But, ideally you would minimalize the communication initiated from PHP to WebSocket -> That's the opposite of what I'm trying, as basically any websocket 'broadcasting' will be triggered from within PHP (according to this logic). It may be better to do it the other way around then? Send messages directly to the node.js websocket channel, from there, forward it to the PHP Controller processing the request, then forward the message or not based on the response received from the PHP Controller via websocket protocol?

@DevelJoe that's triggering a channel. I've meant about minimalising communication once you have a WebSocket channel issued from PHP. So, PHP issues a new connection, but, once it's created, your WebSocket's duplex channel is the thing the user ideally communicates through. Surely, you need to create that channel, but once you create it, ideally you do not issue too many commands from PHP to the already existent channels.

This approach would most likely reduce the total amount of roundtrips to the minimum (ws - php - ws), making the architecture also more portable. Like, I could try out different websocket tools like a node.js server, or maybe also e.g. AWS' websocket API, while I just need to handle connection establishment, closing and forwarding the request to my own server for the PHP processing. Guess that makes the most sense?

@DevelJoe the reason for that is that your user is doing, let's suppose some profile editing. It is great if the profile edit command is issued through WebSocket connection and that transmits it to PHP via the access token of the channel. Not to PHP and then transmit it to WebSocket if you already have a connection :)

@DevelJoe there is nothing wrong with creating the WebSocket connections the way you prefer. WS is just a good tool and it is advisable to use the WS connection to as much of the communication as possible and you can use your backend by WS forwarding the intercepted messages/events.

Ok so to sum it up, the way to go is i) login through PHP as normally done, ii) send access token from PHP back to client, iii) client fires request to initiate websocket connection to the websocket server with obtained access token, iv) ws validates access token by forwarding it to the PHP server, v) if valid, opens the connection, if not, does not initiate / close the connection. Then, for any further requests, the client sends the request directly to the ws channel, then steps iv and v are performed, and then vi) the ws connection forwards messaging events to the required recipients. Yes?

And as soon as a connection is established, the traffic is ws - php - ws for the concerned endpoints (v and the REST controller are both performed via the single ws - php (HTTP) request). As you seem to have experience with websocket solutions, do you recommend any tool / language for it over node.js? Have you any experience with the AWS Websockets API? Seems favourable to be able to outsource the websocket service out of my VM resources.

@DevelJoe the process you discovered is correct, yes, this is how ideally you could operate with WebSockets. Later on you will likely find exceptions from the rules we laid down and if you have a good reason to break them, don't hesitate to do so (for example an admin blocks a user, so PHP needs to actively shut down a WS connection, but there are often neat solutions for these scenarios too). For NodeJS this tool seems to be useful https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket . I have been using WebSocket in various tech stacks, such as SignalR in .NET or my own PHP WS tool.

@DevelJoe I have also used WebSocket in React, but for that purpose the WebSocket part was the responsibility of a team-mate, so I do not recall exactly what was in use.

Thanks a lot mate!

@DevelJoe happy to help!

actually, a little question. Why it is a problem to send requests from PHP to the ws; you said that should be reduced to a minimum? The thing is, many endpoints of my web app are actually bound to the messaging system. Consequently, using the ws - php - ws communication logic would need to be applied to many many endpoints, which is a significant amount of work. Why can't I use the connection establishment as mentioned above, and then pushing events from PHP to the ws channels, as shown in the example of http://socketo.me/docs/push ? Would be ideal to push messages to current ws-connecions?

@DevelJoe it is not a necessity, but if you keep the usage of multiple endpoints of your PHP being actively used even though you would be able to trigger them from an existent WS connection, then, when you debug issues, particularly related to the information flow and message/event handling, it will be messy to have to figure out for each and every flow how exactly it is being handled. If you have a consistent or almost consistent approach to do so, then it will be way easier to maintain the project. It's therefore not a technical necessity, but a good-to-have

@DevelJoe you are not forced to refactor all the already existent endpoints into your WS setup, because that would postpone the date of your next release, but, if you slowly gravitate to the ideal state by having the new actions follow the advised flow and occasionally refactor some things you already had (for example you need a big refactor to an already existent feature, you can squeeze in the flow change there too), then you will end up having a close to ideal scenario.

@DevelJoe I do understand that you likely have some form submits that directly send requests to the end points that you have, which, in turn look into $_POST or $_GET or something like that and it would be a huge effort to change everything in hindsight. The solution is to not to it at once. You have legacy code and you do not want to rewrite it. So, with the idea of "what happened in Vegas stays in Vegas" you could say that you do not touch the legacy code for the sole reason of refactoring, but later, when you touch it anyway, you can also refactor it. Gradually.

Well my approach would be consistent; it would always be PHP > ws once the connection is established. And the establishment of the websocket connection is done as explained above. The REST API's actions then still only work through PHP. I only need the websockets to immediately receive the messages on all clients to no longer need to rely on polling for that. So to me it makes more sense to use the PHP Controllers used for the REST API Endpoints to trigger the push of all messages over the ws channels. Changing the entire API to work over websockets seems like overkill for this to me.

I've now come across two new possible options, which may be more suitable to this: X) I see that redis has a pub/sub feature. So I could add a simple PHP code to write the PHP messages resulting from the controller calls into the pub/sub queue of redis. Then, configure the said node.js server to listen to that redis channel and forward accordingly through ws. OR, Y) listen to DB changes of the messages table of my system. Everytime an INSERT or a UPDATE happens, trigger the node.js channel. What do you think about these approaches?

@DevelJoe yes, you can do that way too. Consistency is the goal, so if you have an idea of how it should work and you stick to that idea apart from exceptions when you need to delve from it for some reason, then I see no issue. X) with Redis and Y) with DB are both feasible approaches to handle messaging of the like you described.

Thanks again mate!
